# Optimisation of RAM

Tags: vhdl, ram

I'm currently debugging my DPRAM. As usual, simulation works perfectly but in real life it fails. The syntax is as such:

```
ram[Address][Data]
```

I can get the data to write to the first 8 addresses but anymore and the data is just lost (even on chipscope). As a work around, I stitched two pieces of DPRAM together with a simple logical switch to re-route the data to the second DPRAM after it hit the eighth address. This worked but it just looks so messy.

My thinking is that it is being optimised away, even if it isn't this will be a good learning curve anyway (and any thoughts on this are welcome).

Here is the signal variable in the DPRAM with my effort at stopping it from being optimised away:

```
type ram_array is array(16 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
shared variable ram: ram_array;


attribute KEEP: string;
attribute KEEP of ram_array : type is "TRUE";
```

I think I need to add a line to the UCF file also though I can't seem to get the syntax right, with entity name path obviously changed:

```
NET "entity/name/path/dpram/ram_array" KEEP ="TRUE";
```

So is this how I'd add the code if I wanted to stop optimisation?

EDIT:

Output (guess there wasn't optimisation):

```
Found 17x32-bit dual-port RAM <Mram_ram> for signal <ram>. Summary: inferred 1 RAM(s). inferred 65 D-type flip-flop(s). Unit <dpram> synthesized.
```

Thanks =)

Comment: Shared variables are usually bad news : one aspect of this is that some synthesis tools may have poor or buggy support for them. Recommend making ram a signal, and then verifying that you can get the correct behaviour in simulation before proceeding.

Comment: What makes you think it is being optimized away? You mention a UCF so I suspect you are using Xilinx tools...they will issue plenty of warnings when something is optimized away. By the way, how many bits do you expect will be in this RAM and what size FPGA are you using to implement it?

Comment: Using an SP601. I want a total of 10 addresses (perhaps more in the future), each with 32 bit words. I don't understand why copying this code into two slaves works, whereas doing it all in one go doesn't...

Comment: If feasible, then make a stand-alone synthesis of only the module with the RAM, and check the synthesis reports to see if the required amount of RAM is implemented.  Any warnings may also be easier to spot for a smaller design.

Comment: It's not possible to make a stand-alone synthesis of the project. I figured it'd be quite easy to quickly implement those "keeps" above but I can't get the syntax right in the UCF.

Comment: Tried using a "variable" instead  it turned out to be the same...

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use shared variable for synthesizable code**

If your code needs to be synthesizable, then don't use shared variable.

**Inferring BlockRAM**

If you need sample code to implement your memory without using a shared variable, use the documentation provided for your FPGA.

Sample doc links :

- (xilinx) http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_2/xst_v6s6.pdf
- (altera) http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii51007.pdf

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand how it should work in theory, but it simply doesn't so I wanted to see how to stop optimisations. The only real difference is I using rising_edge instead of clk'event...

Comment: Have you changed your code to replace the shared variable by a signal as Brian Drummond told you ?

Comment: Yes and it acted the same

Comment: Have you checked the warnings given by your implementation tool for the signal related to your memory (Especialy the read and write address signals) as Joe Hass told you ? Things are not optimized away without an information given by the tool.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. Here is some output:

`Found 17x32-bit dual-port RAM <Mram_ram> for signal <ram>.
 Summary:
 inferred   1 RAM(s).
 inferred  65 D-type flip-flop(s).
Unit <dpram> synthesized.`

Comment: My two stitched together RAMs: `17x32-bit dual-port RAM                               : 2`

Comment: Are you sure your addressing is correct ? Words are 32 bits words, thus you will have the first 32 bits word at address 0x00, the second at address 0x01 and so on (don't suppose addressing is for 8 bits words). Thus the 16th 32 bits word will be at address 0x0F, and the 17th 32 bits word at address 0x10.

Comment: Yes I am sure. This data is actually an event, so I know 32 bits are stored in each address, I have 9 events in total at the moment (but can only read the first 8). This is then addressed correctly. When I do a debug, it says only 8 words have been stored and it can't read the 9th word as it doesn't exist. When I stick two blocks of RAM together, the 9th goes back to the first address of the second RAM - so it did exist.... I can't think of why... Especially since simulation works...

Comment: I also checked the number of address locations my software allows from the inferred RAM - and it's 32 - well within the 16 I want.

Comment: You can try to write more data in your RAM to see when the first data are overwriten, and with what value. If your simulation is not a post-layout one, it is another things you can try. I am also a bit confused  when you speek about "your software"... Is it this software that says there is only 8 words, and thus based on what information ? Does your simulation include this software part ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The software I am using is an interface between the FPGA and the computer, written in C++. It works on the other FPGAs we have and detects block RAM, reading it out. The software (which isn't wrong) is telling me that it can only read the first 8 words on the SP601, displaying an error message for the 9th.

Your point on data being overwritten is an interesting one as the 9th word doesn't overwrite the first word when I have just the one RAM (and not the stitched together version).

Comment: And not the simulation doesn't include the software